# Apache rewrite using RewriteCond/RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have two test sites `http://foo/abc`, `http://foo/def`.

I'm trying to understand the `RewriteCond`/`RewriteRule` process to use vhost to emulate the alias/directory directive.

The "abc", "def" sites can be served using the alias/directive block. I'm trying to figure out if apache can do the same thing using vhost blocks, combined with `RewriteCond`/`RewriteRule` logic.

Basically, trying to see if/how vhost can be used to serve a specific site using the combination of `RewriteCond`/`RewriteRule` to restrict the site being displayed.

It appears that something like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$          /var/www/html/abc [B,L,QSA]
```

would work, but the browser errors out on this.

Pointers would be welcome.

Comment: not sure i've made my question clear. I'll try to explain. Basically, I want to use vhost (if possible) to take a look at the url [http:// foo /abc..] and if the url has "/abc" then I want the vhost rewritecond/rules block to go ahead and passthru/serve up the page.    so the rewritecond would look for "/abc" and if there, the rewriterules would set the correct url/file (similar to the alias process).    if "abc" isn't in the url, the vhost/rewrite logic wouldn't do anything to the url.   i've got a number of urls and i'm wondering if vhost/rewrite can be used this way.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the browser produces an error, because the directory `/var` (and therefore everything in it) is not published via apache.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question right that you try to emulate virtual hosts with ModRewrite.

Yes that is possible when your first RewriteCond checks the domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
```

But note that this just work with HTTP/1.1 like with virtual hosts that bases on hostnames and not IPs.